# POST запрос к ASP.NET странице

Tags: asp.net, android, http, post

Доброго времени суток. Может кто подсказать из-за чего приходит ответ от асп.нет страницы с ошибкой 500?

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://site.ru/login.aspx");

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()); //<- тут лежит страницы с ошибкой.
```

Пробовал даже дописывать хэдар

```
httppost.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
```

Причём пост идёт пустой и всё равно ошибка...

зы. андройд

Comment: А может просто скажете сайт, куда запрос уходит? это будет значительно лучше.

А может просто потому что он пустой или из-за того, что Вы андроид макинтошем прикрыли:)

Answer (score 2):

не важно на "какую" страницу идет пост, asp это, java или php все они используют http протокол.
500 - это Internal Server Error/  И смотреть нужно в первую очередь на эту "страницу" работает ли она.